# Documentum error : [DFC_OBJPROTO_BAD_NUMBER_FORMAT]

Tags: documentum, documentum6.5, documentum-dfs, documentum-dfc, documentum7.3

I am trying to get the content of all the documents (current version) from a documentum source using the following code

```
IDfSysObject document = (IDfSysObject) session.getObject(new DfId(eachFileMetadata.get(some document id).toString()));
ByteArrayInputStream docContent = document.getContent();
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ObjectProtocolException:: THREAD: Thread-708; MSG: [DFC_OBJPROTO_BAD_NUMBER_FORMAT] Invalid number format for value count in serialized object; ERRORCODE: ff; NEXT: null
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.objectprotocol.ObjectProtocolException.newBadNumberFormatException(ObjectProtocolException.java:38)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.objectprotocol.AbstractObjectProtocol.deserializeInteger(AbstractObjectProtocol.java:94)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.objectprotocol.AbstractObjectProtocol.deserializeRepeatingValue(AbstractObjectProtocol.java:215)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.objectprotocol.AbstractObjectProtocol.deserializeValue(AbstractObjectProtocol.java:203)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.objectprotocol.ObjectProtocolV0.deserializeObject(ObjectProtocolV0.java:76)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.objectprotocol.ObjectProtocolV0.deserializeObjectWithPossiblyExtendedType(ObjectProtocolV0.java:150)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.objectprotocol.ObjectProtocolV0.deserializeObjectWithPreamble(ObjectProtocolV0.java:115)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.netwise.NetwiseDocbaseRpcClient.applyForObject(NetwiseDocbaseRpcClient.java:687)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection$8.evaluate(DocbaseConnection.java:1382)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection.evaluateRpc(DocbaseConnection.java:1141)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.connection.docbase.DocbaseConnection.applyForObject(DocbaseConnection.java:1374)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.docbase.DocbaseApi.parameterizedFetch(DocbaseApi.java:107)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.objectmanager.PersistentDataManager.fetchFromServer(PersistentDataManager.java:191)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.objectmanager.PersistentDataManager.getData(PersistentDataManager.java:82)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.objectmanager.PersistentObjectManager.getObjectFromServer(PersistentObjectManager.java:355)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.objectmanager.PersistentObjectManager.getObject(PersistentObjectManager.java:311)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.Session.getObject(Session.java:963)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.SessionHandle.getObject(SessionHandle.java:653)
```

the above error occured when I am trying to get the content of a document,can anyone please help me??